# Checking request JSON with image data

Tags: json, debugging

I've ran into an issue, where I need to check the sent `JSON` structure with image data inside, currently I can check the request in the browser inspection tab, but the data is too long and the check freezes the browser tab.

**My question is**: Can I somehow minimize the sent `JSON` and display its structure instead of loading in the entire image data on request?